# "object" does not contain a definition for 'Name'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am using Json.Net package and my problem is when i want to get the value of an index it gives me an error like this "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'"

here is my GetData.cs file content:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class GetData
{
    public string Name{set;get;}
    public string ReleaseDate{set;get;}

    public object GetBasic(){

        string json = @"{
          'Name': 'Bad Boys',
          'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00'}";

        GetData Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetData>(json);
        return Data;

    }

}
```

and this is my test.cshtml file content:

```
@{
    GetData Data = new GetData();
    var objects = Data.GetBasic();
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        @objects.Name
    </body>
</html>
```

thank you in advance for help

Comment: Are you using the full-blown MVC, or WebMatrix?

Comment: You can improve your naming. `GetData` usually doesn't make for a good class name. It is more suited for a method because if contains an action ("get"). It is better to name your class so that it describes the actual thing that is models. In your case that could be something like `Album` or `Book` (or whatever it is that has a release date).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this in three ways, **first one** is by changing the return type of the `GetBasic` from object to `GetData` then the signature of the method will looks like the following:

```
public GetData GetBasic()
{
   // do Something here
}
```

In this case you need not to change anything more, your code will works fine as you expected.

**Second option** for you is change the method call without changing the method definition, which will looks like the following:

```
GetData objects = (GetData)Data.GetBasic();
```

Which will Work since GetData having field called `Name`.

**Third option** is make `GetBasic` as a constructor like the following:

```
public object GetData()
{    
     string json = @"{'Name': 'Bad Boys','ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00'}";    
     GetData Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetData>(json);
     return Data;
}
```

So that you can use like this:

```
 GetData DataObjects = new GetData();
 // DataObjects.Name will have the expected value
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the return type of `GetBasic`  to `GetData` to get the definitions.

```
public GetData GetBasic() {

    string json = @"{
      'Name': 'Bad Boys',
      'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00'}";

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetData>(json);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious issue is that `GetBasic()`'s return type is `object`. So change that to the actual type:

```
public GetData GetBasic()
{
   // ...
}
```

However, you seem to be bypassing all constructs that apply to OO, C# and MVC. You especially should not be doing this work in your view, but in the controller, and you should decorate your view with a model annotation.

So the controller will look like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = new GetData().GetBasic();
        return View(data);
    }

}
```

And the view like this:

```
@model GetData

...

        @objects.Name
```